# node js db.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having this error I can't figure out how to fix;

```
TypeError: db.get is not a function
routes\boxes.js:20:25
server.js:45:5
```

**database.js**

```
module.exports = {    
    'url' : 'mongodb://localhost/database'    
};
```

**server.js**

```
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

var db = require('./config/database.js');


// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(db.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'secretkeykeykeykey' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes/routes')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport
var boxes = require('./app/routes/boxes');

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});

app.use('/portal', boxes);

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

**boxlist.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BoxlistSchema = new Schema({
      name: {
           type: String
      },
      //insert your other key of collection
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Boxlist', BoxlistSchema);
```

**boxes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var collection = require('./boxlist');

/*
 * GET boxlist.
 */
router.get('/boxlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('boxlist');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

/*
 * POST to addbox.
 */
router.post('/addbox', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    // var collection = db.get('boxlist');
    db.collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});

/*
 * DELETE to deletebox.
 */
router.delete('/deletebox/:id', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('boxlist');
    var boxToDelete = req.params.id;
    collection.remove({ '_id' : boxToDelete }, function(err) {
        res.send((err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg:'error: ' + err });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**global.js**

```
// Boxlist data array for filling in info box
var boxListData = [];

// DOM Ready =============================================================
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Populate the box table on initial page load
    populateTable();

    // Boxname link click
    $('#boxList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkshowbox', showBoxInfo);

    // Add Box button click
    $('#btnAddBox').on('click', addBox);

    // Delete Box link click
    $('#boxList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkdeletebox', deleteBox);

});

// Functions =============================================================

// Fill table with data
function populateTable() {

    // Empty content string
    var tableContent = '';

    // jQuery AJAX call for JSON
    $.getJSON('/portal/boxlist', function (data) {

        // Stick our box data array into a boxlist variable in the global object
        boxListData = data;

        // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
        $.each(data, function () {
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowbox" rel="' + this.boxname + '" title="Show Details">' + this.boxname + '</a></td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.vm + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeletebox" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });

        // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
        $('#boxList table tbody').html(tableContent);
    });
};

// Show Box Info
function showBoxInfo(event) {

    // Prevent Link from Firing
    event.preventDefault();

    // Retrieve boxname from link rel attribute
    var thisBoxName = $(this).attr('rel');

    // Get Index of object based on id value
    var arrayPosition = boxListData.map(function (arrayItem) {
        return arrayItem.boxname;
    }).indexOf(thisBoxName);

    // Get our Box Object
    var thisBoxObject = boxListData[arrayPosition];

    //Populate Info Box
    $('#boxInfoName').text(thisBoxObject.fullname);
    $('#boxInfoVm').text(thisBoxObject.vm);
    $('#boxInfoDescription').text(thisBoxObject.description);
    $('#boxInfoVersion').text(thisBoxObject.version);

};

// Add Box
function addBox(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Super basic validation - increase errorCount variable if any fields are blank
    var errorCount = 0;
    $('#addBox input').each(function (index, val) {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            errorCount++;
        }
    });

    // Check and make sure errorCount's still at zero
    if (errorCount === 0) {

        // If it is, compile all box info into one object
        var newBox = {
            'boxname': $('#addBox fieldset input#inputBoxName').val(),
            'init': $('#addBox fieldset input#inputBoxInit').val(),
            'vm': $('#addBox fieldset input#inputBoxVm').val(),            
            'description': $('#addBox fieldset input#inputBoxDescription').val(),
            'version': $('#addBox fieldset input#inputBoxVersion').val()
        }

        // Use AJAX to post the object to our addbox service
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: newBox,
            url: '/portal/addbox',
            dataType: 'JSON'
        }).done(function (response) {

            // Check for successful (blank) response
            if (response.msg === '') {

                // Clear the form inputs
                $('#addBox fieldset input').val('');

                // Update the table
                populateTable();

            } else {

                // If something goes wrong, alert the error message that our service returned
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);

            }
        });
    } else {
        // If errorCount is more than 0, error out
        alert('Please fill in all fields');
        return false;
    }
};

// Delete Box
function deleteBox(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    // Pop up a confirmation dialog
    var confirmation = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this box?');

    // Check and make sure the box confirmed
    if (confirmation === true) {

        // If they did, do our delete
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: '/portal/deletebox/' + $(this).attr('rel')
        }).done(function (response) {

            // Check for a successful (blank) response
            if (response.msg === '') {} else {
                alert('Error: ' + response.msg);
            }

            // Update the table
            populateTable();

        });

    } else {

        // If they said no to the confirm, do nothing
        return false;

    }

};
```

**portal.js**

```
<!-- views/profile.ejs -->
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Vagrant CLI Node API</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 80px;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/global.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="page-header text-center">
            <h1><span class="fa fa-th"></span> Portal</h1>
            <a href="/profile" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Profile</a>
            <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Logout</a>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <!-- AVAILABLE BOXES -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div id="boxList" class="well">
                    <h3><span class="fa fa-th"></span> Available Boxes</h3>

                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Vm</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- BOX INFO -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="well" id="boxInfo">
                    <h3><span class="fa fa-th"></span> Box info</h3>

                    <p>
                        <strong>Select box name for more information</strong>
                        <br>
                    </p>

                    <p><strong>Name:</strong> <span id='boxInfoName'></span>
                        <br/><strong>Vm:</strong> <span id='boxInfoVm'></span>
                        <br/><strong>Description:</strong> <span id='boxInfoDescription'></span>
                        <br/><strong>Version:</strong> <span id='boxInfoVersion'></span></p>

                    <a class="fa fa-plus" href="#">
                        <i></i> start box instance and add to account</a>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- ADD NEW BOX -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="well">
                    <h3><span class="fa fa-th"></span> Add box</h3>

                    <p>
                        <strong>Add new box to `available boxes`</strong>
                        <br>
                    </p>

                    <form id="addBox" class="form-inline" action="/portal/addbox" method="post">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <input id="inputBoxName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Boxname" />
                            <input id="inputBoxInit" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Init" />
                            <input id="inputBoxVm" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Vm" />
                            <input id="inputBoxVersion" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" />
                            <input id="inputBoxDescription" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Version" />
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <button type="submit" id="btnAddBox" class="btn btn-primary">Add Box</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anybody know what's going on and how to fix this? My code *excludes node_modules* [link to dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41330678/api.rar)
Thanks

PS. Parts of these codes are from this tutorial: [link](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/) which can be forked from GitHub: [link](https://github.com/cwbuecheler/node-tutorial-2-restful-app). This code works, but I've implemented it into my own application and as far as I know it's now the same code, but I get the error in my app, but not in his app.

Comment: It look like you don't have any `get` method in yout `database.js` module. Not sure you're omitting the code, but for sure you have to provide the full code if you have. Or follow a [tutorial](http://blog.modulus.io/mongodb-tutorial), if this is all your real code. Than come back here if you still have issues.

Comment: unable to understand `var collection = db.get('boxlist'); ,is it the complete code?

Comment: Added the entire code in server, database and boxes js. I've added passport to my app and that works, I can create the passport user database and add users to it. But I am also trying to create new boxes which I get this db.get error.

Comment: Is the `database.js` file content mentioned in your question the one that is required using `require('./config/database.js');`?

Comment: It's under database.js. The code entirely works for passport auth., but not for the other part.

Comment: Is your 'boxlist' a schema ?

Comment: I am using a schema for passport users, and that works. I've added some more code to my question. The part to add boxes does not use the scheme. It rather uses global.js I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do one thing, remove `db.get('boxlist');`

Make a new file with the name **boxlist**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BoxlistSchema = new Schema({
      name: {
           type: String
      },
      //insert your other key of collection
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Boxlist', BoxlistSchema);
```

In your boxes.js add

`var collection = require('/boxlist');`

now you can directly use queries,need not use `var collection = db.get('boxlist');`

Just delete this line from the code.

Comment: I'm getting cannot find module boxlist...... Must I create boxlist.js in the same folder as boxes.js? Than the path should be "require('./boxlist');"? I've also tried "require('./app/routes/boxlist');"

Comment: because you are not defining the path properly, check where have you put this file, if it is in the same folder as boxes.js just put `var collection = require('./boxlist');`

Comment: Sorry my head is all mixed up. I get the error var Schema = require mongoose.Schema unexpected identifier. boxlist.js:2. Removed require and it starts up.

Comment: My bad, i have edited the answer, just check again. FYI remove `require` from var Schema = require mongoose.Schema;`

Comment: "now you can directly use queries" How to use queries directly now?

Comment: you can directly use `collection.insert(req.body, function(err, result){});`, these type of queries without using that `var collection = db.get('boxlist);` line. Hope you are getting me.

Comment: But when I remove the db.get I get the following error: "collection.insert is not a function" :'( "   TypeError: collection.insert is not a function
   at C:\Git\nodejs\api\app\routes\boxes.js:21:16 at C:\Git\nodejs\api\server.js:46:5"

Comment: try put `db.collection.insert`, instead of juts `collection.insert`, it should work!

Comment: same error........ "collection.insert is not a function" after db.collection.insert. My system is cursed.

Comment: i dont know where it is going wrong, can you update the question!!

Comment: I've made the changes in my question

Comment: Bro, testing whole thing will take time, you upload the code on the drive and can share the link to me on ajitej.delhite@gmail.com. I will get back to you by tomorrow. I will test it on my other machine where i have setup for node.

Comment: Hey, link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41330678/api.rar just run npm install because I've excluded node_modules. Thanks man

Comment: Hey, I've managed to make it work *kinda*, whenever I press add box, it craetes the database and table now, but does not add the data to it except _id. Should I accept the answer and post it to another new question?

Comment: I've closed this question and moved to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506135/node-js-empty-database-table because I think this question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define port number for accessing database.

Eg:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/database
```

To fetch collection follow documentation https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html

```
var collection = db.collection('test');
```

Comment: Both work, with port and without. Error still there.

Comment: "db.collection is not a function" Why is this any different that db.get?

Comment: I've tried: `mongoose.connect(db.url),
    function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            return console.dir(err);
        }

        db.get('boxlist', function (err, collection) {});
    };` in server.js, but still db.get not a function in boxes.js

Comment: Don't use db.get() method. Follow mongoose guideline to connect and access collections. http://mongoosejs.com/

Comment: db.get() method is not exist.

Comment: The code I'm using is part from here: https://github.com/cwbuecheler/node-tutorial-2-restful-app, but there is no db.get there either and it works there. Or does it have db.get function?

Comment: They are using old versions. Some 2 years back stuff. May be you need to map your express and MongoDB version with that project.